# Text to roll up on hover of background image

Tags: html, css

I'm new to CSS and would like to make some text roll up when I hover over a particular background image. For example, http://kulturecity.org/ on the right side, the three images. I've been able to position it where I want on the page, but am not able to achieve the hover effect.

```css
.wedo {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 33.33333%;
}

.wedo-section {
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
 height: 200px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.28);
}

.wedo-section.hover {
 background: rgba(0, 124, 178, 0.8);
}

.wedo-section:last-child {
 border-bottom: none;
}

.wedo-section .inner {
 display: table-cell;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 vertical-align: middle;
 padding: 0 30px;
}

.wedo-section .inner h2,
.wedo-section .inner h3 {
 font-size: 48px;
 margin: 0px;
 color:#333;
 font-weight: 700;
}



.wedo-section .inner p {
 color: #666;
}

.wedo-section .inner a {
 color: #666!important;
}

.wedo-section a:hover {
 color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6)!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="wedo bounceInRight animated">
     <div class="wedo-section" style="background:url(Images/wedo1.png) 70% 50% no-repeat">
         <div class="inner">
             <h2><a href="http://ipdorthocentre.tidalismdesign.com">About Us</a></h2>
                <div class="add">
                    <p><a href="http://ipdorthocentre.tidalismdesign.com">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="wedo-section" style="background:url(Images/wedo1.png) 70% 50% no-repeat">
         <div class="inner">
             <h2><a href="http://ipdorthocentre.tidalismdesign.com/">Programs</a></h2>
    <div class="add">
                 <p><a href="http://ipdorthocentre.tidalismdesign.com/">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wedo-section" style="background:url(Images/wedo1.png) 70% 50% no-repeat">
         <div class="inner">
             <h2><a href="http://ipdorthocentre.tidalismdesign.com/">Get Involved</a></h2>
    <div class="add">
                 <p><a href="http://ipdorthocentre.tidalismdesign.com/">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the body's background to black so you can see the effect. (Watch the snippet in full screen)

```css
body {
  background:#000;  
}

.wedo {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 33.33333%;
}

.wedo-section {
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
 height: 200px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.28);
}

.wedo-section:hover {
 background: rgba(0, 124, 178, 0.8);
}

.wedo-section:last-child {
 border-bottom: none;
}

.wedo-section .inner {
 display: table-cell;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 vertical-align: middle;
 padding: 0 30px;
}

.wedo-section .inner h2,
.wedo-section .inner h3 {
 font-size: 48px;
 margin: 0px;
 color:#333;
 font-weight: 700;
}



.wedo-section .inner p {
 color: #666;
}

.wedo-section .inner a {
 color: #666!important;
}

/*.wedo-section a:hover {
 color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6)!important;
}*/

.add {
  max-height:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  transition:all .3s ease;
}

.wedo-section:hover .add {
  max-height:100px;  
}

.wedo-section .inner {
  transition:all .3s ease;  
}

.wedo-section:hover .inner {
    background:rgba(0,216,255,.7);
}
```

```html
<div class="wedo bounceInRight animated">
     <div class="wedo-section" style="background:url(Images/wedo1.png) 70% 50% no-repeat">
         <div class="inner">
             <h2><a href="http://ipdorthocentre.tidalismdesign.com">About Us</a></h2>
                <div class="add">
                    <p><a href="http://ipdorthocentre.tidalismdesign.com">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="wedo-section" style="background:url(Images/wedo1.png) 70% 50% no-repeat">
         <div class="inner">
             <h2><a href="http://ipdorthocentre.tidalismdesign.com/">Programs</a></h2>
    <div class="add">
                 <p><a href="http://ipdorthocentre.tidalismdesign.com/">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wedo-section" style="background:url(Images/wedo1.png) 70% 50% no-repeat">
         <div class="inner">
             <h2><a href="http://ipdorthocentre.tidalismdesign.com/">Get Involved</a></h2>
    <div class="add">
                 <p><a href="http://ipdorthocentre.tidalismdesign.com/">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It seems to be on the right track, however when I tested the code on Safari, it doesn't work there. It seems to work fine on Google Chrome. Also, like in the http://kulturecity.org/ website, I would like a color background to come on hover so the text shows clearer. How do I do that?

Comment: I just updated my code.  Is the test was on the PC or MAC?